# Windows Phone 8 Uninstall event?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a web service that contacts my Windows Phone8 app at specified intervals.

The service needs to be notified when the user uninstalls the Windows Phone8 app.

Is there an uninstall event of some type ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an uninstall event of some type ?

No, there is no way to know that a user uninstalled your app (with the current Windows Phone SDK).